# app.route not working in browser while working fine in mobile - Polymer1.0

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I have polymer 1.0 app. In  my routing.html file I have following configuration for routes.

```
        page('/applications', function () {
          app.route = 'Applications';      
        });  

        page('/claims', function () {
          app.route = 'Claims';
        });
```

I have applied data-routes attr in index.html file to map the corresponding section part.

For Ex:

```
<a data-route="Claims" href="/claims">
              <iron-icon icon="report-problem"></iron-icon>
              <span>Claims</span>
            </a>

           <section data-route="Claims">
             <div class="vertical layout center">
                <div>                
                  <p>Getting Claims...</p>
                  <paper-progress value="10" secondary-progress="30" class="" indeterminate elavation="4"></paper-progress>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
```

So the main problem occurs when I try to change the routes through a function. In my case I am calling a function on paper-fab tab event

I want to change the route  when a user click on paper fab, to achieve this I defined a  method "createApplication" in app.js

```
          app.createApplication = function() {   
            app.route = 'Create Application';
          };
```

and section part for this route in index.html file

```
  <section data-route="Create Application">
      <div class="vertical layout center fit">
        <p> Some content</p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

The problem is when I click on the paper -fab its not changing the route in browser but same code runs fine in mobile.

Comment: does your browser-console say anyhing?

Comment: Its pain, no error message is appearing  browser console. It seems that polymer lacks for debugging mechanism.
Well  this is the video of runing app. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3s4iB6urTTw&feature=youtu.be